# The values in my matrix are automatically signed to 0 by MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix and I just want to change the first 3 rows of it. However,after I changed the rows, I lost all the values in 4th, 5th and 6th row.

```
PositionMatrix_color
PositionMatrix_color(1:3, :) = image_matrix;
PositionMatrix_color;
```

The result for above code is :
[image]

After I changed first 3 rows, the result become:

```
PositionMatrix_color;
PositionMatrix_color(1:3, :) = image_matrix;
PositionMatrix_color
```

[image]

In fact, there is a e+04 displayed on the top of it. Each column represents a pixel of my picture. The first 3 values are (x, y, z). I have z because I want to make a grayscale depth image later. The 4th, 5th, 6th contain the RGB information. When I open my picture after I changed the first 3 rows, all my RGB automatically changed to 0 or 1.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the values of `PositionMatrix_color` and `image_matrix` before running your code?

Comment: My bet is you have something like `1.0e+06 *` displayed on top of that. If that's the case, it's just a dislpay issue (scientific notation); try `PositionMatrix_color(4,1)` to see each entry individually

Comment: You are right, e+04 is displayed on the top. But the values on the 4th, 5th, 6th are definitely not the previous values

Comment: Did you try displaying a single value like @LuisMendo suggested? A value of `0.0049` is going to be `0.00000049e+04` which is going to show up as `0.0000e+04` unless you display an element individually, or maybe use `format long` to show more decimal places.